# Working with User.Identity.GetUserId()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this code that returns 0

```
var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var businesses = db.Businesses.Where(num => num.BusinessEmail == currentUser);

ViewBag.CurrCount = businesses.Count();
```

And this code that returns 7

```
var businesses = db.Businesses.Where(num => num.BusinessEmail == "myname@mysite.com");

ViewBag.CurrCount = businesses.Count();
```

**myname@mysite.com** is User.Identity.GetUserId();

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

I was a little tired last night!